# Break away/Break in angle in Root Locus method

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, root-locus

We are learning Root Locus in our introductory controls course, and one thing has really been confusing me.

When the poles are on real axis, is the breakaway angle *always* 90 degrees? Is there a simple example of a transfer function with real poles that has a non 90 degrees break away/ break in angle? What about a system with not necessarily just real poles? Can it have a non 90 degrees break away/ break in angle?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The answer of your question can be easily found in any authentic book of Control Systems. Nevertheless, there is a direct expression to determine the angle of breakaway/in which is:

**theta = (pi)/n** where n is the total number of root locus branches approaching/leaving the point(breakaway/in point).

If there are 2 branches, let's say leaving from the breakaway point, then only the angle is 90 degrees, otherwise not.

For more details, refer the following video of nptel explained by Prof. M Gopal:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPQvS9XxlNk&list=PLA74601484F6994D8&index=31